# Problema para consumir Web Service

Tags: c#, webservice

Soy nuevo en esto de los Web Services.

Tengo el siguiente [WebService](https://cotizaciones.bcu.gub.uy/wscotizaciones/servlet/awsbcucotizaciones?wsdl)

Necesito obtener la cotización de la moneda para el día actual pero no estoy pudiendo obtener ningún dato.

Lo estoy intentando hacer en C#, ya agregue la referencia al Web Service pero no puedo obtener los datos.

El parámetro de entrada es un tipo de dato estructurado llamado wsbcucotizacionesin el cual contiene:

```
Moneda[Item] - Numerico(4)
FechaDesde - Date
FechaHasta - Date
Grupo - Numerico(2)
```

Luego tengo el parámetro de salida que es un tipo de dato estructurado llamado wsbcucotizacionesout el cual contiene:

respuestastatus - es un tipo de dato estructurado donde tira los códigos de error
datoscotizaciones - tipo de dato estructurado donde contiene información de la moneda que consulte (Fecha, Moneda, Nombre,....)

Yo me hice un Form donde tengo un txt para poner la moneda y un botón para enviar la llamada, pero no estoy obteniendo nada y tampoco se muy bien como es que se hace.

Hice dentro de mi botón:

```
WebReference1.wsbcucotizacionesin test = new WebReference1.wsbcucotizacionesin();

test.FechaDesde = fecha.ToString();
```

Me pueden dar una mano de como se tendría que hacer o encaminarme para saber como obtengo los datos que quiero del Web Service.

Comment: Hace falta mas información sobre la clases, sus metodos y sus propiedades.

Comment: hs ensañado el webService por aparte?

Answer (score 2):

Como dice @Veelicus deberias poner mas código, adicionalmente, WS al recibir de las fechas en string, debes conocer cual formato espera, ya que  podría ser diferente al que al que estas enviando, ya que una el resultado del ToString depende de la configuración regional
Este es un ejemplo del xml que se deberia estar generando

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cot="Cotiza">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cot:wsbcucotizaciones.Execute>
         <cot:Entrada>
            <cot:Moneda>               
               <cot:item>2223</cot:item>
            </cot:Moneda>           
            <cot:FechaDesde>2017-06-05 12:00:00</cot:FechaDesde>
            <cot:FechaHasta>2017-06-05 23:00:00</cot:FechaHasta>
            <cot:Grupo>0</cot:Grupo>
         </cot:Entrada>
      </cot:wsbcucotizaciones.Execute>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```